# How do I fix the grid from the A* pathfinding project

Tags: unity-game-engine, a-star

I am using the A* pathfinding project in my unity project but the grid I created sees the whole terrain as not walkable even though I set the obstacle layer mask to the "unwalkable layer" and only the walls of the building have that layer so only they should be unwalkable right?

[image: Image of grid]

[image: Showing that the walls are unwalkable]

[image: Showing the obstacle layer]